# jquery and sliding/animated background

Tags: jquery, animation, background

I want to make something like this site: http://www.lionite.com
Check the header, the city slides, how can this be done with jquery ?

Any plugin or tutorial would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: I think this is what you seek http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really simple, and that site burns my CPU a lot (no idea why, it shouldn't do that - it's simple :P)

What You want is animating background position on a div or the whole body.

1. create a background that can be repeated horizontally
2. do the css so that it's shown and repeats on x
3. use $().animate() on background position changing the x position up to the width of your background
4. when animation ends change the x position back to 0 and run amination again.

it will look like You are scrolling the background all the time (if You synchronize it badly it will jump a bit on every position restart )

If You don't know how to do the css position bug me in comments ;)

Comment: I agree, it's burning ~16% cpu in Chrome. That's pretty damn awful for a company website, especially when animating something so simple

Comment: On my 5yr old laptop usnig ff3.0 on ubuntu I got 100% CPU with that :D What is really amazing is that the animation was still smooth! :D